# See all my questions across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange, linked-accounts

Is there a way for me to see all my questions across all Stack Exchange sites?

If not, how about just to see which sites I have subscribed to?

Comment: Wow, I was literally just about to ask the same question. I feel I need a Stack Exchange dashboard.

Comment: April 27 2023: Summary of the status. Despite having accepted and upvoted answer no method has actually been suggested that shows you all your questions across all stack exchange sites. You can get either get all recent questions. Or all questions for one site at a time. I'm really hoping some future feature will change this or someone manages a more efficient way to extract this information somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accounts tab on the user profile page will give you all the sites you have subscribed to.

As for the question in the title, You will have to go through the stats tab in each of your Stack Exchange site profiles.

Comment: This answer is outdated, here's the current method that I'm aware of: go to SE, click on your user icon (top right), select "activity" tab, select "posts" tab. This will display all your questions from all sights, but also all your answers. This is the closest thing to what you're asking for I believe.

Comment: Outdated? Worked fine for me.

Comment: @Otherness: this is a great answer! :). Pls make it one and ill vote for it

Comment: @ScottWelker, the outdated part is "You will have to go through the stats tab in each of your Stack Exchange site profiles." There is now a much better method that doesn't require this. See the answers by Jeff and cregox. It is misleading that this answer that basically says "sorry nothing better to do than search each SE site separately is still the top answer when a much better answer exists. This should be edited to either include the better method or to say on the top that it contains an outdated needlessly cumbersome method.

Answer (score 10):

This is a feature planned for http://stackexchange.com -- to have a master profile with your "greatest hits" across all sites.

Now completed! Details at

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92734/can-i-view-favorites-from-all-se-sites-at-one-place/92735#92735 (2011-05-26) refers to Jeff's blog post about Stack Exchange network profiles.

Comment: I want to see all my questions and not just the "greatest hits" - also to be able to search them would be nice.

Comment: Great! It would be even greater if this answer could contain a direct link to the relevant page rather than a link to a blog!

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work anyway. It only shows the most recent results. Any way to show all results?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for very late answer, but this helped me finding the question I was looking for: [my StackExchange Activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/102214/cawas?tab=activity).

Just replace it for yours:

```
https://stackexchange.com/users/102214/cawas?tab=activity
```

Or simply go to your SE **profile** and **click** on **activity**! :P

Comment: Just because it confused me I will add: The user id shown on your profile at meta.stackexchange is not the correct one. You have to go to your profile on stackexchange.com and check your ID there. Replacing the above ID with this ID works. BTW replacing the account name does not actually matter. So a slightly cleaner format is `https://stackexchange.com/users/SEuserID/?tab=activity`

Comment: This only shows recent results though right? For posts it shows me the last two years. For comments only a few months.