# View "cross-site" favorites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks, stackexchange.com

Is there an easy way to view all my favorite questions on a single page, without checking every StackExchange site?

For exemple: 
I have a favorite question on stackoverflow, but I'm currently on SuperUser.
If I visit my SuperUser profile, I have no favorite question (yet ;-). I have to go to stackoverflow, then view my profile again, and finally check again my favorite.

As a new StackExchange fanatic, I would be delighted to follow all my favorite questions at once.

How can I do it easily?

Thank you!

Comment: This is actually not a duplicate - [See all my questions across all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74222/is-there-a-way-for-me-to-see-all-my-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites) is about showing my own questions and answers, while this question is about my favorite questions (by others).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like this is now possible - you need to check your "network profile". Go to StackExchange.com, log in and click the "logged in" link at the top. There's a favorites tab you can look at which works across all the sites.

Comment: Simpler way to get there: Follow the "Network Profile" link under your picture on your profile.

Comment: I was late to reply! Still time, I hope, to thank you for the link

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to propose something like this when I found this question. It seems that this is not possible right now.

Some ideas how it might be done:

- Have a page at stackexchange.com, [linked from my profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/3687974d-c7d4-45c3-8eae-759a11847f5d) (or a separate tab there) which shows all my favorite questions - just like the [single-site favorite lists](https://stackoverflow.com/users/600500/paulo-ebermann?tab=favorites&sort=recent).
- Allow incorporating this into the filters, e.g. have a "only my favorite questions" checkbox on the "add filter rule" dialog part. This would allow "all questions + all sites + only my favorites".
  It might be that this is not easily possible, since the filters don't now anything about people ... so maybe "only user ...'s favorites". (But this then will not work easily across sites. Hmm.)

  Actually I would like to be able to include all my favorite changes (on all sites where I have marked some favorite) between the changes on [my favorite sites and my favorite tags](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/palos-filter-small-tags-sites), and I don't really care how this is done.