# Rename "Favorite" vote type to "Bookmark" in VoteTypes table SEDE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

Over at [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/), in [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1292870) query, it shows the vote type (or what *should* be the vote type) "bookmark" as "favorite":

[image]

Can we update that to say "bookmark", since [favorites are known as bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks)?

Comment: I'm checking to see if there was a reason why we didn't make the name change and will circle back here.

Comment: @Taryn my bet would be on backward compatibility. I've seen some SEDE queries that try to prevent magic numbers (kudos to those SQL experts) and do a `select id from Votes where Name = 'Favorite'`. Changing it to say Bookmark would break that. When this was announced I asked Adam if a new VoteType would be introduced and that came back negative due to being too much work. Naming things is hard, even after 6 to 8 years ...

Comment: @rene Yes that could be part of it. I did a quick check and there are only about ~150 queries that reference `name = 'Favorite'` and none have been executed this year, so the breakage on popular queries would be very minimal.

Comment: Everybody knows the correct way to reference those magic numbers is similar to `VoteTypeId = 5 -- Favorite` </rolls eyes>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This changed was pushed to production today, so when SEDE refreshes over the weekend it should be visible.