# How do I view all my bookmarks across all communities?

Tags: support, search, bookmarks

How do I view all my bookmarks across all communities? I.e., see all bookmarks between Stack Overflow and Software Engineering and so on without needing to search through each one individually.

I know this is answered somewhere on meta, but for the life of me, I can't find it (ironically, I forgot to bookmark it). I'm hoping this will make it easier to search in the future.

Answer (score 8):

You can find it in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current), it's one of the tabs there. Or you can use this direct link: https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=bookmarks. Here's how it looks like for me:

[image]

As @ShadowWizard notes in the comments, it only shows the 150 highest scoring/newest/... bookmarked questions (depending on the tab). If you want a complete list, you'll need the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I wrote (kind of) that query here: [Cross-site inbookmarks:mine search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315037/295232) – it <s>allows</s> requires you to search for a keyword as well, which isn't a bad idea in such a long list.

Comment: Worth to mention it's limited to 150 bookmarks, and not sure what' the sort order, so it's not perfect. To see *all* bookmarks, one will have to find other way. (API, perhaps?)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard you can't trick the pagination? Not sure since I don't have that many bookmarks. SEDE would be my alternative if that didn't work.

Comment: [No](https://stackexchange.com/users/bookmarks/201110?page=6&sort=votes&_=1623310508191), you get "No bookmarks found." if you try to request page 6. (Using OP profile as example, he has more than 150 cross network.)

Comment: @DanielKaplan I understand your edit, but you should edit your network profile (with the "Update profile info" link) then as well, and upload another avatar ...

Comment: This doesn't work any more, maybe they got rid of the tab when they migrated bookmarks to saves a few months ago.

Comment: @Glorfindel is there a URL that takes you right to the saves? The one that takes you to bookmarks no longer exists.

Comment: @DanielKaplan it seems this option disappeared when migrating bookmarks/favorites to saves.