# I wanted to access a saved question, but I forgot which site it was on

Tags: support, saves

Recently, I wanted to access a question I had saved, but I wasn't sure which Stack Exchange site the question was on. I tried going to my network profile, but there isn't any "network-wide" saves page that I could find, so eventually I had to re-google the question, filtering through the many many similar-sounding other questions, and thus defeating the entire purpose of the "saves" feature.

For what it's worth, the question was *[How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)* [sic], and it was on [the Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

In this case, I wasn't sure if it was on my Stack Overflow, my [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), my [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), or something else. How could I have more easily found the question that I already saved, besides re-googling or going through each of my individual sites' saved pages?

Comment: Sadly, there's no way. That's one useful feature that they removed, as it used to be available in the network profile indeed. But that's how things work, features are sacrificed to make place for other features, we can't have it all. :/

Comment: @xdavidliu, these are the very old requests to implement this feature: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18506/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78946/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75302/282094 - it has since been broken by the evolution of bookmarks into saves. --- Perhaps instead of support this would make a great feature request. --- Unfortunately the search term "in:saves" doesn't work on the main network site, only on all the other sites.

Comment: Also related: [Merged list of all favourites from all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384845/merged-list-of-all-favourites-from-all-stack-exchange-sites)