# Merged list of all favourites from all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, stack-exchange, bookmarks, network-profile, saves

Until recently I was accessing a list of all of my starred or favourited questions via the following URL:

https://stackexchange.com/users/1309702/jimadine?tab=favorites

This would list all favourites from across all Stack Exchange sites.

The above URL now returns a `Page not found` message.

I understand that Favourites have been replaced by [Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves). However, there appears to be no equivalent https://stackexchange.com/... URL for Saves. Saves only appear to be accessible via the individual sites, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/... and naturally are the favourites specific to the site.

How can I list all of my favourites from across all Stack Exchange sites in one merged list, as I was able to do before?

Comment: The same thing applies to `tab=bookmarks`.