# See all joined community's question in one page

Tags: support

How do I see all joined community's questions in one page?

For example, I joined Stack Overflow and Cross Validated, how do I see Stack Overflow's and Cross Validated's questions in one page so I don't have to go to the different websites to look for them.

Note: This question is not [duplicate of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74222/see-all-my-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to https://stackexchange.com

- Click on filtered questions button.
- Click on my sites link

[image]

You get:

[image]

Or you can narrow down the filter and create a custom one in the form.

Comment: Can i do the same, using the app?

Comment: @Abochur I havent been able to find such an option in the app... You can create a shortlist of your sites and see individually only.

Comment: @SurajRao: When I click 'my sites', it only show all the questions but not tagged questions. If I click favortie tags, it only shows the tagged questions but not the sites without tagged questions. For me, the best situation is that it shows all the sites' questions but only show the tagged questions if that site has favorite tags. If the site doesn't has favorite tags, it shows all the questions. In short, how to make it show questions exactly the same as questions in a individual site?

Comment: @LionLai you can make a custom filter... select all questions and select the required sites. Then select add rule and enter the tags and the sites of the favorite tags..

Comment: @SurajRao: It's a hard work. Besides, it can add different tags on different site. But in 'my filter' click, it can only tags and apply these tags to all sites I select. Can I add different tags on different sites I select?

Comment: I agree its hard work... You will have to keep adding rules for this and really customize it. Or hope someone else knows of an easier way @LionLai